# C# WPF How to change a red rectangle around a textbox to a red circle with exclamation mark

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls, errorprovider

I have a `TextBox` which is connected to a class property.

```
<TextBox Name="txtbSleeveLength"   
         Grid.Row="0" 
         Grid.Column="1" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         Height="23" Margin="1" 
         Text="{Binding Path=SleeveLength, StringFormat=N2}" 
         Width="120" 
         TextAlignment ="Center" 
         GotFocus="txtbSleeveLength_GotFocus" />
```

Property from class

```
public class SleevePattern : Shape, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 //...
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    //...
    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    //...
  public double SleeveLength
    {

        get { return sleeveLength; }
        set
        {
            if (value != sleeveLength)
            {
                sleeveLength = value;
                Notify("SleeveLength");
            }

        }
    }
    //...
```

}

As the property is not nullable, two effects take a place. At the beginning there is  “0.00” in the `TextBox` and if the `TextBox` is not fulfilled a red rectangle appears around the text box.

**Now questions**
 What `TextBox` property is responsible for this rectangle(if such exists)? I heard that there is `ErrorProvider`. Can it be used in XAML tags to get the exception and change the rectangle to the red circle with exclamation mark?

Comment: By adding Validation.ErrorTemplate = "{x:Null}" (<TextBox x:Name="txtbSleeveLength" Text="{Binding SleeveLength, StringFormat=N2}" TextAlignment ="Center" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" GotFocus="txtbSleeveLength_GotFocus" />, I received the rectangle does not appear anymore around the TextBox. But it was not an answer to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be using a Border, and a Style for it.

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SleeveLength}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <TextBox ...></TextBox>
        </Border>
```